# How to query for all users that bought from a store knowing their orders

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say you have 3 tables (users, products, and orders) and these tables meet the following requirements:

- the product table has a storeID field
- the orders table has a productID and userID field

What's the best way to query for all unique users when you only know the storeID?

Answer (score 1):

All methods will give you the same results

I would prefer to use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM users u
INNER JOIN products p ON p.userID = u.ID
WHERE 
    p.storeID IN(SELECT storeID FROM orders)
```

In my opinion, best if you start your query with the smallest table, while using JOIN with large tables, so you can be more selective in the join part and would make your query elegant, and have some performance improvement.

you could be more selective by adding more conditions to the query where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Could describe the columns available in your tables?
Are you able to try something like this?

```
select distinct userID
from store_table as a
inner join order_table as b on a.storeID=b.storeID
inner join user_table as c on b.userID=c.userID
where a.storeID='xxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.UserName 
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Products P ON O.productID=P.productID
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID=O.UserID
WHERE P.StoreID=Input_StoreID
```